How to get `say` command to stop saying "comma" instead of just pausing
When this line is read by Siri (Voice 4), found under Spoken Content > System voice, it pronounces "comma" after "Africa" instead of just pausing:
say "Illegal mining is common in South Africa, once the world's largest gold producer, now home to thousands of abandoned mines."

Yet, for some reason, it is only that first comma, not the second. I thought maybe it had something to do with the fact that "Africa" is a pronoun. I tried lower-casing it, though, and the result was the same.
For now I am just planning on preprocessing all the text read by say to replace , with  [[slnc 300]]. This is a possible solution for me since I am calling it from a Go program.
But is there a more universal way to eliminate this behavior?
In the age of AI, I would expect a more reliable real-time macOS native reading program to exist but I haven't found one. APIs using Google's free service inherit its character limit of 200 characters, which is an unacceptable trade-off for me, and other APIs I've found are even lower quality than say.

Does it have to be that voice? It doesn't work at all when I try it. All the others that I tested work fine.

I prefer at least a Siri voice for quality and I've definitely had the other Siri voice I use do it.

I guess it’s subjective, but the “enhanced” voices sound at least as good to me as the Siri voices, if not better.

@LincDavis, in Siri settings you need to set the voice to Voice 4 so that the voice is downloaded and installed. Then it works.

@ChrisRedford, it actually works fine for me and doesn't break at all. I just copied and pasted and it's working as expected.

@Alex I don't know what to tell you. I can repeat the error with complete consistency. But it may point to some setting you have set that I don't or vice versa.

@ChrisRedford, I believe you. Just tough when it's not reproducible. Oddly, I had the Siri 4 voice in the drop-down for System Voice, but then when I went back after downloading different Siri voices it stopped being available in System Voice completely. Today it's back, but doesn't actually say anything.

This has to be a bug. In System Voice, if you hit the i you can use the voice picker to download the Siri voices. For me that makes the say command work and use them. Trying various options, eg 'say "South Africa, Hello"', triggers it. So does South America and South Australia. South Austria doesn't. Nor does South England or South Germany. Weird edge case?
